# How to cache JSON response from API with Ktor Client?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I am working on a Kotlin app. I am using Ktor Client for network calls. Now I want to cache the JSON response and need to show those when device has No Internet connection. I need to update those offline cached data also when internet becomes available.

HttpCache feature provided by Ktor but it is only for response header.

I have tried with installing the plugins HttpCache, but it is not working as per my requirements.

```
HttpClient {
   ...        
   install(HttpCache)
   ...
}
```

How can I achieve this with Ktor client?

Comment: What do you mean that the HttpCache plugin is only for response header?

Comment: HttpCache plugin is response header driven and I am not able to override it because number of classes are Internal.

Comment: Yes, because it works according to the specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234. You can take the source code of the `HttpCache`plugin as an example to implement an unconditional caching mechanism.